# Reorder factor variable by mean of variable within that factor

Tags: r

Suppose my data looks something like this:

```
set.seed(782015)
df1 <-
  data.frame(name = factor(sample(
    x = LETTERS[1:4], size = 1000, prob = c(.25,.25,.25,.25), replace = T
  )),
  number = rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 100, sd = 10))
```

I want to reorder the factor variable `name` by having the one with the highest `mean(number)` first and the lowers last. In this example it should be:

```
  name        
1    B 
2    C 
3    D 
4    A
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Thanks!

---

To clarify:

```
 levels(df1$name)
 [1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
```

I want it to return B C D A

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want (wait for it...) `reorder`.

```
> df1$name <- reorder(df1$name, -df1$number)
> levels(df1$name)
[1] "B" "C" "D" "A"
```

Comment: clever name for that function!

Comment: Learned a new function today

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
ag <- aggregate(number ~ name, df1, FUN=mean)
levels(df1$name) <- ag[order(ag$number, decreasing=T),]$name
```